# delete attribute in custom class derived C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

using EF Core Power tools to create database models in Blazor, I need to customize the models in derived classes, but I can't remove the object validation attributes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I do it?

```cs
public partial class Test
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime DataInserimento { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string User{ get; set; }
    public bool Deleted{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomTest : Test IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmptyName
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Set Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've provided code that wouldn't compile. That's unhelpful. Ideally, provide a [mcve] - or at least provide *actual code that compiles* and give precise details about the expected results vs actual results.

Comment: " I need to customize the models in derived classes, but I can't remove the object validation attributes."  What stops you?  What derived classes?   What's that `yield return new ValidationResult("Set Name");` all about?  `yield return` is normally only used it iterators.